# Snowflake RegEx syntax woes

Tags: regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for some help diagnosis what I'm doing wrong, when applying a working RegEx expression to Snowflake (specifically [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_replace.html)).

I'm trying to replace commas (not within a quoted section) with another string. I've tested and confirmed that the expression returns the desired result in regex101.com, but when I try and apply it to a Snowflake query I'm not getting any results.

I've seen references in the REGEXP_REPLACE() documentation (indicating the need for additional escapes on brackets) which I have applied - still no dice.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing??

Sample text (C1):

```
99999999999,"SOME CORPROATION, Dissolved January 17, 1983",123 SOME STREET #760,,Denver,CO,90210,,,,,,,,Voluntarily Dissolved,CO,Corporation,JOHN,F.,DOE,,,1512 SOME STREET #760,,DENVER,CO,90210,US,,,,,,,03/29/1886
```

Working Regex:

```
(?:[^"\']|(?:\".*?\")|(?:\'.*?\'))*?(,)
```

My interpretation of SF reqs for RegEx:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE((C1), '\\(?:[^\\"\']|\\(?:\".*?\"\\)|\\(?:\'.*?\'\\)\\)*?\\(,\\)', '","') AS "blah"
```

Comment: Please post the exact command with the regex you are using. Also, try `([^,"']|".*?"|'.*?')*(,)`. Note the `(,)` is now in Group 2.

Comment: Hi Wiktor - the exact command I'm passing is: ```REGEXP_REPLACE((C1), '\\(?:[^\\"\']|\\(?:\".*?\"\\)|\\(?:\'.*?\'\\)\\)*?\\(,\\)', '","') AS "blah"```

Comment: Can't help with the expression as it is very complicated but I can tell you that grouping brackets do not need to have \\ so when trying your expression Select REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMN1,
'(?:[^\"\']|(?:\".*\")|(?:\'.*\'))*(,)', '","')
FROM VALUES('99999999999,"SOME CORPROATION, Dissolved January 17, 1983",123 SOME STREET #760,,Denver,CO,90210,,,,,,,,Voluntarily Dissolved,CO,Corporation,JOHN,F.,DOE,,,1512 SOME STREET #760,,DENVER,CO,90210,US,,,,,,,03/29/1886'); 

gives error

Invalid regular expression: '(?:[^"']|(?:".*")|(?:'.*'))*(,)', no argument for repetition operator: ?

Answer (score 1):

just discovered that Snowflake only offers support for Posix Standard and Extended RegEx, so usage of non-capturing groups is not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a solution that works rather than specifically a REGEX solution, then the following UDF should do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replace_char("in_text" string, "replace_text" string, "skip_text" string)
  RETURNS string
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
    var out_string = '';
    var skipping = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < in_text.length; i++) {

        if (in_text.charAt(i) == skip_text) {
            skipping = !skipping;
        } 

        if (skipping === false && in_text.charAt(i) != replace_text) {
                out_string = out_string +  in_text.charAt(i);  
            }
        else {
                if (skipping === true) {
                    out_string = out_string +  in_text.charAt(i); 
                }
            
        }
    }    

  return out_string;
$$
;
```

In order to be productionised it would need error handling, checks on the inputs, etc. but this should be enough to get you started.

You can use it as follows:

```
set intext = '99999999999,"SOME CORPROATION, Dissolved January 17, 1983",123 SOME STREET #760,,Denver,CO,90210,,,,,,,,Voluntarily Dissolved,CO,Corporation,JOHN,F.,DOE,,,1512 SOME STREET #760,,DENVER,CO,90210,US,,,,,,,03/29/1886';
set replace_text = ','; -- char to remove from $intext
set skip_text = '"'; --Between matching occurrences of this char no text will be replaced

select replace_char($intext,$replace_text,$skip_text);
```